# Python 3.3 with Pillow - ImportError: No module named 'Image'

Tags: pygame, python-3.3, python-imaging-library

I have this code:

```
import Image

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

catImg = Image.open("cat.jpg")
```

I am using Python 3.3 and latest version of Pillow. But when I run this code I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'Image'
```

I uninstall PIL. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 16):

Seems you're using an incorrect import, try:

```
from PIL import Image
```

instead.

Comment: If I add from PIL I get:   ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: In that case you don't have PIL or Pillow (which goes by the same package name) installed correctly, it's not on your path. You need either of them for this to work.